# Initialize an array from the dimensions of another array

Tags: c#

Is there a method to initialize a non-jagged array based on the rank of another array?
I don't want to use dynamic things/reflection.

I was thinking I could build a jagged array from the ground up every time using recursive functions but that seems slow + I only want nice rectangular arrays such as float[,].

(Or would it be possible to iteratively create a non-jagged array?)

Basically this is what I want.

```cs
Array func(Array x) 
{
    int rank = x.Rank;
    int[] shape = new int[rank];
    for(int i = 0; i < rank; i++)
    {
        shape[i] = x.GetLength(i);
    }
    Array ret = new float[shape];  // I want to do this
    // basically float[shape[0],shape[1],...] except 
    //  I dont know the length of shape beforehand
    
    // processing
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not consider `Array.CreateInstance` [(see System.Array docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array) as more dynamic as your `JaggedArray` implementation, you can create new array instances with the same layout with the following implementation

```
private static Array CreateSized<T>(Array sourceArray)
{
    int[] shape = new int[sourceArray.Rank];
    for (int i = 0; i < shape.Length; i++)
        shape[i] = sourceArray.GetLength(i);
    
    return Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), shape);
}
```

Using `CreateSized` like so

```
int [] a =  { 1, 2, 4, 8 };
Array fa = CreateSized<float>(a);

int [,] b = { { 10, 20, 40, 80 }, {100, 200, 400, 800 } };
Array fb = CreateSized<decimal>(b);
```

You can use the methods `GetValue` and `SetValue` on your array. For writing a value into the array:

```
fb.SetValue((decimal)b[0, 3] * 3, 0, 3);
```

and for reading from the array:

```
fb.GetValue(0, 3)
```

If you know the rank at the use of `CreateSized` you can cast the result and enforce compiletime verification on the number of dimensions.

```
var fb = (decimal[,])CreateSized<decimal>(b);
```

If you don't know the rank at compiletime, the compiler can't know the rank too.

You can also use `dynamic` for the newly created array. Here a small example

```
dynamic fc = CreateSized<double>(b);
fc[0, 2] = b[0, 2] * 3.141592;
Console.WriteLine(fc[0, 2]);
```

Here is a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/52A6sb) version.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I wrote a jagged array version

```cs
public static object JaggedArray<T>(params int[] shape)
{
    object[] ret = new object[shape[0]];
    if(shape.Length == 1)
    {
        return new T[shape[0]];
    } else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < shape[0]; i++)
        {
            ret[i] = JaggedArray<T>(shape.SubArray(1, shape.Length-1));
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: How are you using the result of your method?

Comment: I was using it to save results that are calculated from an array of the original `shape`. I didn't need to keep track of the lengths of each dimension of the newly created array, so it didn't matter that every level except the last one was of type `object[]`.